# Unable to create the column and value from the JSON nested key Value Pair using Spark/Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am working on converting the JSON which has nested key value pair to automatically create the columns for the keys and populate the rows for the values. I don’t want to create the schema as the no of columns (keys) will differ for each of the file. 
I am using Spark version 2.3 and  Scala version 2.11.8.
I am not a scala expert and just started my hands on Scala, so appreciate your inputs to get this resolved.

Here is the sample JSON format

```
{"RequestID":"9883a6d0-e002-4487-88a6-c92f6a504d72","OverallStatus":"OK","ele":[{"Name":"UUID","Value":"53f93df3-6528-4d42-a7f5-2876535d4982"},{"Name":"id"},{"Name":"opt_newsletter_email","Value":"boutmathieu@me.com"},{"Name":"parm1","Value":"secure.snnow.ca/orders/summary"},{"Name":"parm2","Value":"fromET"},{"Name":"parm3","Value":"implied"},{"Name":"parm4"},{"Name":"subscribed","Value":"True"},{"Name":"timestamp","Value":"8/6/2019 4:59:00 PM"},{"Name":"list_id","Value":"6"},{"Name":"name","Value":"Event Alerts"},{"Name":"email","Value":"boutmathieu@me.com"},{"Name":"newsletterID","Value":"sports:snnow:event"},{"Name":"subscribeFormIdOrURL"},{"Name":"unsubscribeTimestamp","Value":"8/14/2021 4:58:56 AM"}]}

{"RequestID":"9883a6d0-e002-4487-88a6-c92f6a504d72","OverallStatus":"OK","ele":[{"Name":"UUID","Value":"53f93df3-6528-4d42-a7f5-2876535d4982"},{"Name":"id"},{"Name":"opt_newsletter_email","Value":"boutmathieu@me.com"},{"Name":"parm1","Value":"secure.snnow.ca/orders/summary"},{"Name":"parm2","Value":"fromET"},{"Name":"parm3","Value":"implied"},{"Name":"parm4"},{"Name":"subscribed","Value":"True"},{"Name":"timestamp","Value":"8/6/2019 4:59:00 PM"},{"Name":"list_id","Value":"7"},{"Name":"name","Value":"Partner & Sponsored Offers"},{"Name":"email","Value":"boutmathieu@me.com"},{"Name":"newsletterID","Value":"sports:snnow:affiliate"},{"Name":"subscribeFormIdOrURL"},{"Name":"unsubscribeTimestamp","Value":"8/14/2021 4:58:56 AM"}]}
```

Expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JiWi.png)

### This is my code.

```scala
val newDF = spark.read.json("408d392-8c50-425a-a799-355f1783e0be-c000.json")
scala> newDF.printSchema
    root
     |-- OverallStatus: string (nullable = true)
     |-- RequestID: string (nullable = true)
     |-- ele: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)

      val jsonDF = newDF.withColumn("colNames", explode($"ele")).select($"RequestID", ($"ColNames"))

scala> jsonDF.printSchema
    root
     |-- RequestID: string (nullable = true)
     |-- setting: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
       val finalDF=jsonDF.groupBy($"RequestID").pivot("ColNames.name").agg("ColNames.value")
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am getting this error while creating the finalDF

<console>:39: error: overloaded method value agg with alternatives:
  (expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (exprs: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (exprs: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (aggExpr: (String, String),aggExprs: (String, String)*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String)
          val finalDF=jsonDF.groupBy($"RequestID").pivot("ColNames.name").agg("ColNames.value")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, `agg` function might be declared in the following ways:

```
agg(aggExpr: (String, String)) -> agg("age" -> "max")
agg(exprs: Map[String, String]) -> agg(Map("age" -> "max")
agg(expr: Column) -> agg(max($"age"))
```

Instead of

```
agg("ColNames.value")
```

you should use one of the above examples.

e.g.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

jsonDF.groupBy($"RequestID").pivot("ColNames.name")
   .agg(collect_list($"ColNames.value"))
```